# When does the hypothesis space contain the target concept

Tags: machine-learning, concept, induction

What does it mean when it is written that-
Hypothesis space contains the target concept?
If possible with an example.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: It means you can learn with zero error.

---

Here is an example what it means: Suppose a concept: `f(a,b,c,d) = a & b & (!c | !d)` (input are in boolean domain).

This concept is in a ML task usualy represented by the data, so you are given a dataset:

```
a | b | c | d = f
--+---+---+---+---
T   T   T   T = F
T   T   T   F = T
T   T   F   T = T
   ... etc ...
```

And your hypothesis space is [decision trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning). In this case your hypothesis space contains target concept, as you can do (for example, there are more possibilities):

[image: decision tree example]

> It can be proven, that any binary formula (concept) can be learned as
>   a decision tree. Thus **General binary formulas are subset of decision trees.** That means, when you know the concept is a binary formula (that you even may not know), you will be able to learn it with a decision tree (given enough examples) with zero error.
>
> On the other hand if you want to learn the example concept by
>   [monotone conjunctions](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr06/cos511/scribe_notes/0209.pdf), *you can't do it*, because binary formulas are not subset of monotone conjunctions.
>
> (By subsets, I mean in terms of possible concepts. And from the subset relation, you can make statements about *containing target concept in hypothesis space*.)

Monotone conjunction is a set of conjunctions in which the variables are not negated. And you have more of those, when any of the conjunctions is true, the output is also true. Is is a subset of [DNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) where you cannot use negations.

Some concepts can be learned by montone conjunctions, but you cannot learn general binary formula concept by it. That means, **you will not be able to learn with zero error, general binary formulas are not subset of monotone conjunctions.**

Here is a nice PDF from Princeton on basics of ML: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr06/cos511/scribe_notes/0209.pdf

Comment: I would say not "with zero error" but with "Bayesian error" or "with smallest error possible", since sometimes a target concept is non deterministic in nature (thus Bayes risk is non zero).

Comment: A concept in terms of the ML lectures is a terminus technicus for a situation where you cannot have different output for a single input. Unique input combination can be in the concept, or not be in the concept. It is a crisp set. That is why I wrote zero error.